# Is it possible to use an alternate ID factory with React Native's Metro bundler?

Tags: react-native

I would like to generate my own module IDs when bundling React Native code with the [Metro bundler](https://github.com/facebook/metro), so that I can bundle a base Javascript bundle, and multiple application-specific bundles that reference it later.

The Metro bundler automatically generates numeric IDs for each module that are referenced by code that depends on them in the bundle.

The Metro Bundle constructor appears to use a [fixed ID factory](https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/master/packages/metro/src/Bundler/index.js#L158):

```
this._getModuleId = createModuleIdFactory();
```

Is it possible to substitute the ID factory used by `metro.runBuild(opts)` without modifying the Metro bundler source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My pull request the React Native Metro bundler was imported, which allows setting a custom ID factory

https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/100

Example of usage (see https://github.com/doubledutch/cli/blob/master/packager.js#L29 for details)

```
await metro.runBuild({
  config: {
    createModuleIdFactory() {
      return (path) => /* some ID */
    },
    ...
  }
})
```